# What is the normal force the ramp exerts on the car?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces

The car rests on a ramp, and by a chain. Calculate the normal force the ramp exerts on the car. The car has a weight of 1500.00. The incline is an angle of 50.00 degrees. Answer in N.

I believe it should be N= 1500cos(50)since the normal force the ramp exerts on the car is equal to the component of the weight perpendicular to the ramp however the online quiz says I am wrong. Can someone tell me if I went wrong somewhere?